# Difference between insertAdjacentElement() and insertBefore()?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to understand the error `DOMException: Node.insertBefore: Child to insert before is not a child of this node` which I've seen in both React and Angular projects over time and I started wondering: why does it even matter if an element A is "a child of" element B? Why choosing `Node.insertBefore()` over `Element.insertAdjacentElement()`?

The way I see it, both have browser support for ages and both work for SVG. But `Node.insertBefore()` seems to have an awkward API to me, because it requires to specify the parent.

Am I missing something?

Comment: node.insertBefore works with nodes, element.insertAdjacentElement works with elements.

Answer (score 5):

`insertBefore()` requires you to provide the parent node, an existing child node, and the new node to be inserted; the new node is put before the child node. The child node has to be an immediate child of the parent node, otherwise you get that error.

`insertAdjacentElement` only requires you to provide an existing node and the new node. The new node is inserted at some place related to the existing node. There's no need to provide the parent node.

`insertAdjacentElement()` is newer than `insertBefore()`, but both have been around for some time.